# Problem with multipe require functions (RequireJS and ArcGIS JS API)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm currently looking for a way to use the module loader [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/) and the [ArcGIS JS API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/) in a project. According to the documentation, the modules of the ArcGIS JS API can be loaded as shown in the following code snippet:

```
require(["esri/config", "esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView"], function (
  esriConfig,
  Map,
  MapView
) {
  //...
});
```

The problem is that if I want to load the modules from the ArcGIS JS API, it actually calls the Require function of RequireJS:

[image]

But it should load the require function which is defined in the ArcGIS JS API:

[image]

RequireJS does not find the modules of the ArcGIS JS API and therefore throws errors in the console:

[image]

My project only supports ES5. For this reason I can't use node libraries like the [esri-loader](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to add the following code:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
      esri: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/esri",
      dojo: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/dojo",
      dojox: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/dojox",
      dijit: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/dijit",
      "@dojo": "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/@dojo",
      cldrjs: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/cldrjs/dist/cldr",
      globalize:
        "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/cldrjs/dist/globalize/dist/globalize",
      maquette: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/maquette/dist/maquette.umd",
      "maquette-css-transitions":
        "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/maquette-css-transitions/dist/maquette-css-transitions.umd",
      "maquette-jsx":
        "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/maquette-jsx/dist/maquette-jsx.umd",
      moment: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/moment",
      tslib: "https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/tslib/tslib",
    },
  });
```

I found this solution in the following project: https://github.com/r-pankevicius/arcgis-js-api-with-requirejs/blob/master/4.13/scripts/main.js

Comment: This worked perfectly as well with ArcGIS 4.16.